# How can i make an update Mysql in symfony2 without refresh the page?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to create the MySQL update to change the value of an input number, so that the changes remain saved when all this is done to manage the cart of the website .

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery is the answer.

http://www.formget.com/form-submit-without-page-refreshing-jquery-php/

Jquery can work magic without refreshing the page.